# Creating a table the same one as in the picture

Tags: tables

I'm new to latex and I want to create a table same as this one and thank you
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please show us what you've tried so far (minimal compilable example, MWE)?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to replicate? The doubled frame lines? The three different types of shading? The font family? The use of **bold lettering** in some columns but not in others? The inconsistent use of uppercase and lowercase spelling? The lack of sufficient whitespace between the left-hand edge line and the words in the first column? Would you be open to generating a table that doesn't slavishly replicate all of the rather questionable design choices embedded in the table shown above? Please advise.

Answer (score 5):

- it seems that is time that you start to read some introduction material about table settings using `latex`, for example [LaTeX/Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)
- table shown in your question is to my taste very ugly
- about design of the nice table, see [Wie Tabellen eigentlich aussehen sollten](https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/)
- considering above link, i propose the following solution:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{siunitx}
  \usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
  \newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}X@{}}{#1}}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                              l
                         *{5}{S[table-format=2.2,
                                group-separator={,}]}
                              @{}}
      \toprule
  Unités d'enseignements
      & \mcx{Coeff. ECTS}    & \mcx{Moyenne} & \mcx{Moy. de la classe} & \mcx{Min} & \mcx{Max} \\
      \midrule
  Français    & 2,0  & 11,40 & 9,76  & 7,00 & 14,60           \\
  Anglais     & 3,0  & 15,25 & 13,41 & 8,65 & 17,08           \\
  $\vdots$    &      &       &       &      &                 \\
  Challenge C & 2,0  & 16,00 & 13,21 & 8,00 & 19,00           \\
      \midrule
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{MOYENNE DU SEMESTRE I}
                     & 11,27 & 10,96 & 8,90 & 13,02           \\
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}

  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%... accepts latin accentuation

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% For table environment %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{multirow}                                               %
\usepackage{color, colortbl}                                        %
    \definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}                                   %
\usepackage{float}                                                  %
%... required for tables and figures in the multi-column            %
%... environment - they need to be placed in specific locations     %
%... with the [H] (e.g. \begin{table}[H])                           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\tw}{\textwidth}




\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{||p{.4\tw}||p{.12\tw}||p{.12\tw}||p{.12\tw}||p{.12\tw}||p{.12\tw}||}%
%... p{<width>} controls the column width
%... each | means vertical border
\hline\hline %-> Generates double horizontal top of the row
\rowcolor{Gray} %-> Makes the next raw become gray
%-> First row contents:
\textbf{Unités d'enseignements} &
\textbf{Coefficient/ ECTS} &
\textbf{Moyenne} &
\textbf{Moy. de la classe} &
\textbf{Min} &
\textbf{max} %
\\ %... returns to second row
\hline\hline %-> Generates double horizontal top of the row
%
%-> Second row contents:
Français &
2,0  &
11,40 &
9,76 &
7,00 &
14,60 %
\\ %... returns to third row
\hline %-> Generates horizontal top of the row
%-> Third row contents:
Anglais &
3,0 &
15,25 &
13,41 &
8,65 &
17,08 %
\\ %... returns to fourth row
\hline\hline %-> Generates double horizontal top of the row
\rowcolor{Gray} %-> Makes the next raw become gray
%-> Merging cells of adjacent columns:
\multicolumn{2}{||p{.575\tw}}{\textbf{MOYENNE DU SEMESTRE I}} &
\textbf{11,27} &
10,96 &
8,90 &
13,02 %
\\ %
\hline\hline %-> Generates double horizontal top of the row
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: This is caused by an error LaTeX issues when measuring the sizes of the cells with borders. Try to replace that line by:
`\multicolumn{2}{|p{.579\tw}}{\textbf{MOYENNE DU SEMESTRE I}}`

Comment: @CarLaTeX I just corrected my answer. Try it now :)

Comment: Now a `|` at the beginning of the `MOYENNE DU SEMESTRE I` is missing.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, it is true. Forgive my missing. I am editing the answer right now to the correct one. The change will be:
`\multicolumn{2}{||p{.575\tw}}{\textbf{MOYENNE DU SEMESTRE I}}`